# apt list upgradable only package names

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I can list packages for update with `apt list --upgradable`.
But that gives a list of packages, with other details, one line per package.
I want as an output a single line with the package names, so I can eventually copy-paste (parts of) that line to a `sudo apt install` line.

I did this with

```
apt list --upgradable | grep -v Listing | awk -F '/' '{ printf "%s ",$1 }'
```

(and I still have to remove the `WARNING...`, probably redirecting stderr, but it is in a separate line so it is less of a nuisance).
I wonder if the same can be achieved natively with `apt`, or some other command (`apt-cache`, etc.)

Comment: It seems there's a misunderstanding here. `apt list --upgradable` should show already installed packages that can be upgraded and that can be done with `apt upgrade` or `apt full-upgrade`. Not with `apt install` because they're already installed.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe apt or apt-get has an option to list only package names. Unless there is something to make it with `apt-get -o...`

Here:
`$ apt list --upgradeable 2>/dev/null | cut -d/ -f1 | grep -v Listing`

... is another way to put it.

Comment: +1 for Cool, it's works.

Comment: Save a process today: `apt list --upgradable 2>/dev/null | sed -n 's,/.*,,p'` (In all lines with a slash, remove it and everything that follows, then print the result).

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing things, yes. Unless I have reason to differ from it, i generally try to use an easily understandable method.